# What regex to use for this

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a regex that will find either

- 1 or more dots `.` `..` `...` `....` followed by a space or not followed by anything at all
- 1 or more question marks `?` `??` `???` again followed by a space or not followed by anything at all

How do I write this regex so I can have it do this or that?

Comment: See also: [Open source regex tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\.+ ?$
\?+ ?$
```

(you just need to escape a `.` or `?` with a `\` to match it literally, since those characters have special meanings in regular expressions.)

Prefix either of these with `^` if you want to match lines containing *only* your pattern.

Comment: Close but this will only capture the trailing dots followed by nothing as the `$` will anchor it at the end . I would rather go for `(\.+)(?: |$)`. Check result [here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=781)

Comment: True, although OP didn't specify that it should match lines *only* including . or ? (although I did take "space or nothing" to explicitly require this at the end of the line). still, edited.

Comment: Indeed. Lets wait for the OP's reaction. You got +1 for your solution which is the closest at this time ^_^

Answer (score 4):

If you need both in the same regex:

`(\.+|\?+)`

Or separate:

`(\.+)`

`(\?+)`

And this answer needs to be 30 characters long to submit...

Comment: The OP wants to match the dot or `?` followed by a space or nothing. Wooble solution seems to take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

For the dots, you can use the `+` thing, which specifies one or more occurrences of the preceding string. Also, you'd have to escape the `.` and the `?`, as they have special meanings in regex:

```
(\.+)$
(\?+)$
```

Comment: This pattern will only match for series of dot or `?` followed by nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like the following

```
(\.+|\?+)\s*
```

Comment: I had put that in, but weirdly the page isn't showing it! I just tried to add again now but it is there in edit mode

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group each section...

`(\.+|\?+)( ?)(.+)`

Answer (score 1):

- To match one or more `.` characters followed by a space: `/\.+ /`
- To match one or more `.` characters followed by nothing: `/\.+$/`
- To match one or more `?` characters followed by a space: `/\?+ /`
- To match one or more `?` characters followed by nothing: `/\?+$/`

To match any of these patterns: `/\.+ |\.+$|\?+ |\?+$/`