# Regex not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I'm having troube modifying this regex. Right now it matches `.` or `?` but I want to change it to match dot followed by a space. How do I do that?

```
'('/([.|?])/'
```

By the way, I need the grouping to stay.

Comment: what about the escaping in this regex? . matches everything. If you want to match "." you want to escape it like \.

Comment: @Stuck: wrong, `.` in `[]` doesn't act as a "any char"

Comment: Double posting. -1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155435/what-regex-to-use-for-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
(\. |\?)
```

......

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be:

```
'('/(\. )/'
```

or, if you want a space or a tab or a new-line:

```
'('/(\.\s)/'
```

Note that I only changed the part in the inner parenthesis as that part seems to be the focus of your question.

Answer (score 1):

`/\.\s/` should work for matching a dot followed by a space..

note: `\s` matches *any* whitespace